# JMtere: What can be the reason of sudden spike in Response time graph which then decreased to run consistently?

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, response-time

[image]

[image]

- As seen in the above graphs, Graph no. 1 is the Response time graph and it showed a sudden spike in the middle of the test. But then it seems to be running consistently.
- On the other hand, the throughput graph, Graph no. 2, showed a down spike but not a sudden spike, it gradually decreased. Also, I got two different throughput values, before and after a down spike.
- I first thought it to be a memory issue, but then it should have affected response time as well.

Could anyone help me in knowing the reason behind the sudden spike in the Response Time graph?
And also what could be the possible bottleneck if not memory leakage issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately these 2 charts don't tell the full story and not knowing your application details technology stack it's quite hard to suggest anything meaningful.

A couple of possible reasons could be:

1. Your application is capable of [autoscaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoscaling) so when the load reaches certain threshold it either adds more resources or kicks off another node of the cluster
2. Your application is going i.e. [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) as its heap is busy with stale objects and once the collection is done it starts working at full speed again. You might want to run a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) to see whether the pattern repeats or not

Going forward consider collecting information on what's going on at your application under test side using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) or [SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener/)

Comment: @Dimitri T, thanks for taking the time and sharing your answer!